# Add number in a barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When adding the percentages to the barplots (see code below), the three percentages that belong to the same "variable" are on the same height, and thus not aligned to their respective bar. How to change that?

```
#Sum plot
myd<- data.frame( var1 = rep(c("Newly infected","Mortality","TDR level"),each=3), 
                     samp = rep(c("Scen1","Scen2","Scen3"),3), 
                  V3 = c(3.5,2,NA,8,2,NA,4,5,NA)/1.5, V2 = c(3.5,2,NA,8,3,NA,4,4.3,NA), V1 = c(1.5,0.2,5,5,3,0.2,4,-5,2) ) 

# rshaping data to long form for ggplot2 
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
meltd<- melt(myd, id.vars=1:2) 

ggplot(meltd, aes(x=var1, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(width=0.6),width=0.5) +
  facet_grid(samp~., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black"))+
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))+
  #scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(0,1))
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("V3"="orange","V2" = "red", "V1" = "blue", "Baseline" = "black"))+
  geom_text(data=meltd, aes(label=paste0(round(value*100,1),"%"), y=value+0.4*sign(value)), size=4)
```

[image: Percentages written in barplot]

Comment: There are some parameters you can use within `geom_text` for horizontal and vertical alignment. Some info here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
ggplot(meltd, aes(x = var1, y = value, fill = variable, label = paste0(round(value * 100, 1), "%"))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = 0.5) +
    facet_grid(samp ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(
        "legend",
        values = c("V3" = "orange", "V2" = "red", "V1" = "blue", "Baseline" = "black")) +
    geom_text(aes(y = value + 0.4 * sign(value)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "bottom",
        strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Use `position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)` inside `geom_text` to dodge labels (equivalent to dodging the bars in `geom_bar`).